# Entity Framework core select causes too many queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-performance

I have the following method which is meant to build me up a single object instance, where its properties are built via recursively calling the same method:

```
public ChannelObjectModel GetChannelObject(Guid id, Guid crmId)
    {
        var result = (from channelObject in _channelObjectRepository.Get(x => x.Id == id)
                      select new ChannelObjectModel
                      {
                          Id = channelObject.Id,
                          Name = channelObject.Name,
                          ChannelId = channelObject.ChannelId,
                          ParentObjectId = channelObject.ParentObjectId,
                          TypeId = channelObject.TypeId,
                          ChannelObjectType = channelObject.ChannelObjectTypeId.HasValue ? GetChannelObject(channelObject.ChannelObjectTypeId.Value, crmId) : null,
                          ChannelObjectSearchType = channelObject.ChannelObjectSearchTypeId.HasValue ? GetChannelObject(channelObject.ChannelObjectSearchTypeId.Value, crmId) : null,
                          ChannelObjectSupportingObject = channelObject.ChannelObjectSupportingObjectId.HasValue ? GetChannelObject(channelObject.ChannelObjectSupportingObjectId.Value, crmId) : null,
                          Mapping = _channelObjectMappingRepository.Get().Where(mapping => mapping.ChannelObjectId == channelObject.Id && mapping.CrmId == crmId).Select(mapping => new ChannelObjectMappingModel
                          {
                              CrmObjectId = mapping.CrmObjectId
                          }).ToList(),
                          Fields = _channelObjectRepository.Get().Where(x => x.ParentObjectId == id).Select(field => GetChannelObject(field.Id, crmId)).ToList()
                      }
                     );
        return result.First();
    }

public class ChannelObjectModel
{
    public ChannelObjectModel()
    {
        Mapping = new List<ChannelObjectMappingModel>();
        Fields = new List<ChannelObjectModel>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ChannelObjectMappingModel> Mapping { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentObjectId { get; set; }
    public ChannelObjectModel ParentObject { get; set; }
    public List<ChannelObjectModel> Fields { get; set; }
    public Guid? ChannelObjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public ChannelObjectModel ChannelObjectType { get; set; }
    public Guid? ChannelObjectSearchTypeId { get; set; }
    public ChannelObjectModel ChannelObjectSearchType { get; set; }
    public Guid? ChannelObjectSupportingObjectId { get; set; }
    public ChannelObjectModel ChannelObjectSupportingObject { get; set; }
}
```

this is connecting to a SQL database using Entity Framework Core 2.1.1

Whilst it technically works, it causes loads of database queries to be made - I realise its because of the `ToList(`) and `First()` etc. calls.

However because of the nature of the object, I can make one huge `IQueryable<anonymous>` object with a `from.... select new {...}` and call `First` on it, but the code was over 300 lines long going just 5 tiers deep in the hierarchy, so I am trying to replace it with something like the code above, which is much cleaner, albeit much slower..

```
ChannelObjectType, ChannelObjectSearchType, ChannelObjectSupportingObject
```

Are all `ChannelObjectModel` instances and Fields is a list of `ChannelObjectModel` instances.

The query takes about 30 seconds to execute currently, which is far too slow and it is on a small localhost database too, so it will only get worse with a larger number of db records, and generates a lot of database calls when I run it.

The 300+ lines code generates a lot less queries and is reasonably quick, but is obviously horrible, horrible code (which I didn't write!)

Can anyone suggest a way I can recursively build up an object in a similar way to the above method, but drastically cut the number of database calls so it's quicker?

Comment: The moment EF Core finds parts of your query that it cannot convert to SQL, it will drag the query results into memory and process them there. You have code like `_channelObjectMappingRepository.Get()....` that is impossible for EF Core to analyse so it will be executed once for every row.

Comment: so if i dont use the repositories and just access the context directly, it will improve it?

Comment: Also (I didn't look well at the query but...) can't you do a `join` to avoid those two sub-queries?

Comment: Not just the repository query (that *might* not be too bad), but what about the recursive`GetChannelObject(...)`?

Comment: that is the crux of my question i guess - can I recursively call something like this to build up a query n-tiers deep, and then execute it as one database call? if not, then what other method would you suggest to achieve a similar thing? i.e. an alternative to a huge select ... new {...}

Comment: Think about how you would write this same query in SQL, what would you do there?

Comment: to be honest, i am not sure how I would write it in SQL... i guess a whole bunch of joins?

Comment: And that's really the problem. SQL isn't designed for hierarchical queries like this. There's no nice way to do it really, because you need to get a parent row to be able to figure out what it's child is, and then that child and so on. Each iteration requires another query.

Comment: Is the `ChannelObjectModel` class the entity?

Comment: If you were to replace "_channelObjectRepository.Get(x => x.Id == id)" with a call to EF's DbSet<>.Find() method, You might sometimes save one query if that entity is already loaded in the DbContext ...

Comment: thanks sam - thats good information, i didnt realise that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with EF6, not Core, but as far as I know, same things apply here.

First of all, move this function to your repository, so that all calls share the DbContext instance.

Secondly, use [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) on your DbSet on properties to eager load them:

```
ctx.DbSet<ChannelObjectModel>()
     .Include(x => x.Fields)
     .Include(x => x.Mapping)
     .Include(x => x.ParentObject) 
     ...
```

Good practice is to make this a function of context (or extension method) called for example BuildChannelObject() and it should return the IQueryable - just the includes.

Then you can start the recursive part:

```
public ChannelObjectModel GetChannelObjectModel(Guid id)
{
    var set = ctx.BuildChannelObject(); // ctx is this

    var channelModel = set.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id); // this loads the first level

    LoadRecursive(channelModel, set);

    return channelModel;
}

private void LoadRecursive(ChannelObjectModel c, IQueryable<ChannelObjectModel> set)
{
     if(c == null)
         return; // recursion end condition

     c.ParentObject = set.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == c?.ParentObject.Id);
    // all other properties

     LoadRecursive(c.ParentObject, set);
    // all other properties
}
```

If all this code uses the same instance of DbContext, it should be quite fast. If not, you can use another trick:

```
ctx.DbSet<ChannelObjectModel>().BuildChannelObjectModel().Load();
```

This loads all objects to memory cache of your DbContext. Unfortunately, it dies with context instance, but it makes those recursive calls much faster, since no database trip is made.

If this is still to slow, you can add `AsNoTracking()` as last instruction of BuildChannelObjectModel().

If this is still to slow, just implement application wide memory cache of those objects and use that instead of querying database everytime - this works great if your app is a service that can have long startup, but then work fast.

Whole another approach is to enable lazy loading by marking navigation properties as virtual - but remember that returned type will be derived type anonymous proxy, not your original ChannelObjectModel! Also, properties will load only as long you don't dispose the context - after that you get an exception. To load all properties with the context and then return complete object is also a little bit tricky - easiest (but not the best!) way to do it to serialize the object to JSON (remember about circural references) before returning it.

If that does not satisfy you, switch to nHibernate which I hear has application wide cache by default.

Comment: thanks so much - i am going to give this a try out today... if i get some improvements with it, ill mark this as the answer :)

Comment: @MikeSowerbutts how did it go? :)

Comment: hey, it worked great thanks, sorry i forgot to mark it as the answer - i just did that now. you were really helpful! got the load time to around 2-3 seconds, instead of ~40 seconds, but kept the recursive nature of the code still

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)